# $D_4=\{ id, r, r^2,r^3, s, sr, r^2s,r^3 s \}$ Table

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$D_4=\{ id, r, r^2,r^3, s, sr, r^2s,r^3 s \}$

Make table

---

useful property  $\forall k \geq 0, sr^ks=r^{-k}$ and $r^k s= sr^{-k}$

found on this post $r^2s=sr^2$ but dont want to use it

From Hungerford
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  *& r_0 & r_1 & r_2   &  r_3 & d & h & t & v \\ \hline
    r_0& r_0 & r_1 & r_2 &  r_3 & d & h & t & v \\ \hline
      r_1& r_1 & r_2 & r_3 & r_0 &  h & t & v & d \\ \hline
  r_2& r_2 & r_3 &   r_0& r_1 &  t & v & d & h \\ \hline
  r_3& r_3 & r_0 & r_1 &  r_2 & v & d & h & t \\ \hline
  d& d & v & t &  h & r_0 & r_3 & r_2 & r_1 \\ \hline
  h& h & d & v &  t & r_1 & r_0 & r_3 & r_2  \\ \hline
  t& t & h & d &  v & r_2 & r_1 & r_0 & r_3 \\ \hline
  v& v & t & h & d &  r_3 & r_2 & r_1 & r_0 \\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

New table with just r and s
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
*  & id & r & r^2   &  r^3 & s   & sr   & r^2 *s   & r^3 *s \\ \hline
id& id & r & r^2   &  r^3 & s   & sr   & r^2 *s   & r^3 *s \\ \hline
r& r & r^2 & r^3   & id  &  sr  & r^2 *s   & r^3 *s  & s \\ \hline
r^2& r^2 & r^3 & id   & r  &  r^2 *s  & r^3 *s   & s   & sr \\ \hline
r^3& r^3 & id & r   &  r^2 & r^3 *s   & s   & sr   & r^2 *s \\ \hline
s  & s   & r^3 *s   & r^2 *s     &  sr   & id & r^3 & r^2 & r \\ \hline
sr  & sr   & s   & r^3 *s     &  r^2 *s   & r & id & r^3 & r^2  \\ \hline
r^2 *s & r^2 *s   & sr   & s     &  r^3 *s   & r^2 & r & id & r^3 \\ \hline
r^3*s   & r^3 *s   & r^2 *s   & sr     & s    & r^3 & r^2 & r & id \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

that  is table and end results but not sure could calculate stuff that dosent just have r's. like for example all the rules needed to calculate stuff like im guessing in $D_n$ $r^n=id$ and $r^k=r^{n-k}$ . there is more

Comment: ok. I know how to do it hungerford's way from an example

Comment: Please, as I said to you in another of your posts, try to include as much tags as possible. That will help you other users to find similar question to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D_8=<r,s|r^4=1=s^2,sr=r^3s>$